# Ordering of X with some properties.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let X be an uncountable set. 
Then, is there an ordering < of X such that for any y in X, {`x| x<y`} is countable?

Comment: If we restrict our attention only to well-orderings, then the answer is: not necessarily. In particular, it will be true if and only if $X$ has the smallest uncountable well-orderable cardinality, $\aleph_1.$ I suspect that the answer will be the same (that is, not necessarily) for more general orders, and it's possible that it only works for $X$ of the same cardinality, but I'm not sure right off-hand. It seems a safe bet, though, that if $X$ is large enough, this won't be possible.

Comment: @CameronBuie What if X is just a real number? How can I find such an ordering?

Comment: Well, hilariously, that's an unanswerable question, because it is fundamentally connected to the *Continuum Hypothesis*.

Answer (score 1):

(I'm assuming that you mean a linear order. If it's a partial order then this can clearly be done. Take the discrete order, or partition $X$ into parts of size $\aleph_0$ and order each of them independently like the rational numbers.)

Assuming the axiom of choice, every linear order has a cofinal well-ordered set. Fixing such cofinal set, since the initial segment defined by each point of our cofinal sequence is countable, the cardinality must be equal to the cardinality of the cofinal sequence.

However, if the cofinal sequence is longer than $\omega_1$ then there is a point with uncountably many points smaller than itself.

Therefore, if $X$ has such a linear order, $|X|=\aleph_1$. In the other direction, if $|X|=\aleph_1$ we can order it by the order type of $\omega_1$ in which case it satisfies the requirements.

Comment: I missed seeing your answer while typing my own. Basically, I proved your statement on the existence of a cofinal well-ordered set by hand. Behold the power of ignorance!

Answer (score 1):

There is no total ordering with this property if the cardinality is greater than $\aleph_1$. To see this, assume that $<$ is a total order on $X$, and let $(x_i)_{i\in\alpha}$ be an enumeration of $X$ by the ordinal $\alpha$. Pick an increasing family $(i_j)$ indexed by ordinals $j$ as follows: Assuming $i_k$ has been picked for $k<j$, let $i_j$ be the smallest ordinal greater than all the $i_k$ with $k<j$ so that $x_{i_j}>x_{i_k}$ for all $k<j$. If no such $i_j$ exists, stop. We now have a family indexed on ordinals: $(i_j)_{j<\beta}$ where $\beta\le\alpha$.

Any ordinal $j<\beta$ must be countable, since $x_{i_k}<x_{i_j}$ for all $k<j$, and all the $x_{i_k}$ are distinct. Thus $\beta$ is no greater than the first uncountable ordinal. The cardinality of $\bigcup_{j<\beta}\{x\in X: x<x_{i_j}\}$ is then at most $\aleph_1$. So if $X$ has greater cardinality than this, the construction of $(x_{i_j})$ could have continued beyond $\beta$.

Answer (score 0):

If you define $\leq$ on $X$ by: $$x\leq y\iff x=y$$ then it is a partial order and the sets that you mention are empty, hence countable.

Comment: The strict version of this partial order is the empty relation, which is *not* an ordering on any multiple-element set, so this doesn't work. Slick idea, though.

Comment: @CameronBuie. Thank you. I am not used to *strict* orders in fact, and did not know that they are demanded to be non-empty.

Comment: Only if we want them to be *total* on a set of more than one element. They can (and in fact *must be*) empty if we're (strictly) ordering a singleton or the empty set.

Comment: @Cameron: If you define a partial order as irreflexive and transitive, the empty relation is in fact a partial order of every set.

Comment: @Asaf: That's certainly true. I was inferring "linear ordering" from "ordering," though.